# Trouble in implementing error for react hook form

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, input, react-hook-form

I'm looking to implement the error message in the react-hook-form and I've noticed some behaviours that are really weird and I can't seem to fix them. For instance: In any of the fields, if I fail to meet the stated criteria, the error message will pop up (which is correct). However, if I remove the input, only the error icon will appear and the message will not show.

In addition, I'm having trouble to align the error message according to the input box. I've used margin to do it but it's not responsive.

I've created a sandbox and would really appreciate the help : https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-glitter-s406b?file=/src/App.jsx

Answer (score 0):

You only provided an error message for the `minLength` validator. But if you empty your input completely the `required` validator will kick in. Either remove it or provide a message like you did with the `message` input

```
{...register("message", {
   required: "Message is Required", <- set a message instead of just true
   minLength: {
     value: 3,
     message: "Please enter your message"
   }
})}
```

Comment: ohhhhh ok i get it thanks! do you know how to align the error message? I'm currently playing with the margins but it's not responsive.